# Rails gems and plugins usage in Netbeans

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working with rails 2.3 with netbeans 6.5.1 on vista.  I want to install more plugins from Git in netbeans like shoulda, cucumber etc. I have these questions:

1)  I do not have much knowledge of Git. Is it necessary to install Git to make use of the Git plugins in netbeans? Are gems and plugins dependant on each other?

2)  In case Git is needed and I do install msysgit , for example I can use the command

ruby script/plugin install http://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda.git/ 
     to install shoulda plugin.

```
 How to make netbeans use this plugin or how to include this plugin in netbeans?
```

3) Is RubyMine a better IDE for Rails than Netbeans in terms of more gems and plugins availability?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1) you will need to install git. I recommend installing [GitExtensions](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/), a toolkit to make working with git on Windows more intuitive. It is good to get you started. Now i am doing most git on the command-line anyway.
Then you will need to configure your git to work with github, more [here](http://github.com/guides/using-git-and-github-for-the-windows-for-newbies).

2) I always install my plugins from the command-line, and Netbeans just sees it is part of the project. I never install any gems and plugins from within Netbeans, but i can see from the documentation it is actually just the same (and maybe easier). I found it easier to stick closer to all tutorials and stuff where everything is command-line driven.

3) Opinions differ ;) RubyMine is not free. It suppossedly has better refactoring-support, amongst others. I tried RubyMine once after a long period of Netbeans and did not see the advantage (but maybe i didn't look hard enough).